# Why am I getting an empty string when I try to get my MAC address?

Tags: c#, mac-address

I am trying to acquire my system's MAC address programmatically. I am writing in C#, using a Visual Studios .NET framework on a Windows 10 OS. I have included the System.Net.NetworkInformation namespace (for other .NET novices out there like myself, had to manually add it in the "References" section under the Solution Explorer, then use the "using" keyword). To get the MAC Address, I am using the following code:

```
try
{
    var macAddr =
        (
            from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
            select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()
        ).FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine("MAC address is: {0}", macAddr);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Could not collect MAC Address;\nERROR: {0}", e);
}
```

The output that I am expecting is either:

> Attempting to collect MAC Address...
>
> MAC address is: XXXXXXXXXXXX

Where XXX.... is the 12-character MAC address, or:

> Attempting to collect MAC Address...
>
> Could not collect MAC Address;
>
> ERROR: [error report inserted here]

What I am getting, however, is this:

> Attempting to collect MAC Address...
>
> MAC address is:

where the macAddr variable appears to have collected an empty string.

So... my question is, why am I getting an apparently empty string instead of the 12-character MAC address that I was expecting?

Comment: What is the exception that is generated?

Comment: No exception is being generated. The try statement succeeds, but no MAC address is printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the empty MAC address of your `Software Loopback Interface 1`.
Make sure you have an active connection with a network before attempting to run this code.
Active meaning that the interface is activated (up) and connected to a network with either a DHCP given IP address or a static one.

[image: Loopback Device]

To fix this, you can simply remove all `Loopback Interfaces` from your query via

```
var macAddresses = from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                   where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up && nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback
                   select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
```

Edit, you could do a check regardless of the `OperationalStatus` of your NICs and simply "ask" for non-empty MAC addresses:

```
var macAddresses = from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                   where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString())
                   select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
```

Comment: Ah. I am using a VM with no Internet connection. I can run ipconfig/all on the VM and get, among other values, a 12-digit MAC address, and I am trying to programmatically retrieve that same address. Is there a way to convince the code to skip the Loopback Interface and search for a non-empty MAC address?

Comment: You could do a string check on the `PhysicalAddress` of all devices regardless of the `OperationalStatus`, I'll edit, the answer accordingly, the syntax highlighter is not working well in comments.

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution did not work for me, and I still got an empty string for macAddresses.. I also tried @Iomed's solution to filter it down to Ethernet type, but I got the same result there.

Comment: That is weird... can you post a anonymized copy of your `ipconfig /all`. I accessed my virtual server (HyperV) and had no problems. Which virtualization technology are you using? HyperV, ESXi, XEN?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see the second solution in that edit. The second solution has properly returned the expected MAC address. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many types of network adapters that do not have a physical address like `tunel` or `Loopback`

filter to `Ethernet` type:

```
where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up && 
nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I got the same result as before, a seemingly empty string for macAddresses.